# Multiplicity of eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the Householder matrix $U=I-2uu^T$ we have that the eigenvalue $ -1 $ for $u$ and the eigenvalue $1$ for the eigenvectors perperndicular to $u$.

The determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues. So we have to check the multiplicity of the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ to get the determinant, right?

How can we check the multiplicity of each eigenvalue? It is the dimension of the eigenvector space, right? So do we have to find a basis for each eigenvector space?

Comment: You don't need to find a basis here: $U$ is a [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) wrt an hyperplane perpendicular to $u$. Therefore, $-1$ has multiplicity $1$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation

Comment: So is the multiplicity $n-1$ because we can find $n-1$ linearly independent vectors that are perpendicular to $u$ ? @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: The multiplicity of $1$ is $n-1$, right. Note that the hyperplane and the span of $u$ are in direct sum, so you can consider separately the action of $U$ on both subspaces. And on the hyperplane, $U$ is the identity.

Comment: Is this the only way to see that the multiplicity of $1$ is $n-1$ ? Because I haven't really understood this way. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: Consider $v$ in the hyperplane perpendicular to $u$. Then $u^Tv=0$, hence $Uv=(I-2uu^T)v=v$. Hence $1$ is an eigenvalue. The geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $1$, and here the eigenspace is all of the hyperplane, which has dimension $n-1$.

Comment: So there are $n-1$ vectors that are perpendicular to $u$ because we are in a $n$-dimensional space? @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! :-) @Jean-ClaudeArbaut